# Opengl Es 2.0 - Displaying multiple textures

Tags: android, opengl-es

So I'm able to display 1 texture at a time but I have a problem with displaying more textures. The render function is called for every texture separately (tex_nr), not sure if that's a good approach. Here's the rendering code:

```
private void Render(float[] m, int tex_nr) {

        // Set our shaderprogram to image shader
        GLES20.glUseProgram(riGraphicTools.sp_Image);

        // clear Screen and Depth Buffer, we have set the clear color as black.
        GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        // get handle to vertex shader's vPosition member
        int mPositionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(riGraphicTools.sp_SolidColor, "vPosition");

        // Enable generic vertex attribute array
        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);

        // Prepare the triangle coordinate data
        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mPositionHandle, 3,
                                     GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
                                     0, vertexBuffer);

     // Get handle to texture coordinates location
        int mTexCoordLoc = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(riGraphicTools.sp_Image,
                             "a_texCoord" );

        // Enable generic vertex attribute array
        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray ( mTexCoordLoc );

        // Prepare the texturecoordinates
        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer ( mTexCoordLoc, 2, GLES20.GL_FLOAT,
                      false,
                      0, uvBuffer);

        // Get handle to shape's transformation matrix
        int mtrxhandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(riGraphicTools.sp_Image,
                           "uMVPMatrix");

        // Apply the projection and view transformation
        GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mtrxhandle, 1, false, m, 0);

        // Get handle to textures locations
        int mSamplerLoc = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation (riGraphicTools.sp_Image,
                            "s_texture" );

        // Set the sampler texture unit to where we have saved the texture.
        GLES20.glUniform1i ( mSamplerLoc, tex_nr);

        // Draw the triangle
        GLES20.glDrawElements(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, indices.length,
                 GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, drawListBuffer);

        // Disable vertex array
        GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);
        GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(mTexCoordLoc);

    }
```

And here the loading textures code:

```
texturenames = new int[GameObject.spritePaths.size()];
        GLES20.glGenTextures(GameObject.spritePaths.size(), texturenames, 0);
        for(int i = 0; i < GameObject.spritePaths.size(); i++)
        {
            // Retrieve our image from resources.
            int id = mContext.getResources().getIdentifier(GameObject.spritePaths.get(i), null, mContext.getPackageName());

            // Temporary create a bitmap
            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), id);

            // Bind texture to texturename
            GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0+i);
            GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, texturenames[i]);

            // Set filtering
            GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
            GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);

            // Load the bitmap into the bound texture.
            GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bmp, 0);

            // We are done using the bitmap so we should recycle it.
            bmp.recycle();
        }
```

As a result of this code, only the last loaded texture is displayed and I have no idea why the former ones do not show up. I would be very grateful for any clues!
edit:
Actually, I have just found out that I can display all of the textures that I loaded but only 1 at a time. So I guess that the problem isn't connected with loading? It looks as if each consecutive Render call(my function) prevented the drawing in the previous call...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a call to `glClear()` in your `Render()` method:

```
// clear Screen and Depth Buffer, we have set the clear color as black.
GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
```

This does pretty much what the name suggests, and what's also captured in your comment: It clears all rendering that has been done so far. So if you call the `Render()` method multiple times, only the rendering from the last call will be visible.

If you want to invoke `Render()` multiple times for the same frame, you will need to take it out of `Render()`, and call it only once at the start of rendering the frame.

There's another thing in your code that looks slightly suspicious:

```
int mPositionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(riGraphicTools.sp_SolidColor, "vPosition");
....
int mTexCoordLoc = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(riGraphicTools.sp_Image, "a_texCoord");
```

Unless `sp_SolidColor` and `sp_Image` have the same value, you're querying attribute locations from two different shader programs. Since `sp_Image` is the program you are using, you should pass it in as the first parameter for both these calls.

Comment: Omg... such a stupid mistake... Thank you very much for your help! As you said i probably should do sth with this second shader since I dont even use it. Thanks for pointing this to me, it's just from the tutorial from which I'm learning.